# Why isn't the explicitly provided type used in this generic method?

Tags: java, generics

Near the end of the [Java Generic Methods tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html), there is an example in which the type `T` is explicitly provided to a generic method:

```
boolean same = Util.<Integer, String>compare(p1, p2);
```

> The type has been explicitly provided.... Generally, this can be left out and the compiler will infer the type that is needed

It is unclear from this description whether type inference takes precedence over the explicitly provided type. The behavior of the code below seems to indicate that inference overrides explicit fully qualified typing. If it's not the case, what am I missing here? If it is the case, why does the explicit type syntax still exist?

[Fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/2nDougbCFn0)

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<String, Object> ctx = getAMap();

        // This line succeeds, even though the fully-qualified syntax specifies Integer when attempting to get a String value
        System.out.println(Main.<Integer>getValue(ctx, "STR"));

        Main.<Integer>getValue(ctx, "STR");
        // The same code fails if we try to assign "ING" to `Integer a`, not during the cast in `getValue`
        // Integer a = Main.<Integer>getValue(ctx, "STR");
        // System.out.println(a);

        Main.<String>getValue(ctx, "INT");
        // fails to cast String to Integer during printing, again not during the cast in `getValue`
        // System.out.println(Main.<String>getValue(ctx, "INT"));
        System.out.println();

        // prints "true", not "FooFooFoo"
        System.out.println(Main.<Foo>getValue(ctx, "BOOL"));
        // fails at compile time, because "Main.Foo cannot be converted to Boolean"
        // System.out.println(Main.<Foo>getValue(ctx, "BOOL") instanceof Boolean);
        System.out.println();

        // This case works consistently
        System.out.println(Main.<String>getValue(ctx, "ABSENT"));
    }

    public static <T> T getValue(Map<String, Object> context, String key) {
        if (context.containsKey(key)) {
            Object obj = context.get(key);
            System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
            T cast = (T) obj;
            System.out.println("Cast to " + cast.getClass().getName());
            return cast;
        } else {
             return null;
        }
     }

    public static Map<String, Object> getAMap() {
        Map<String, Object> aMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        aMap.put("STR", "ING");
        aMap.put("INT", 1);
        aMap.put("BOOL", true);
        return new HashMap<>(aMap);
    }


    private class Foo {
        public String toString() {
            return "FooFooFoo";
        }
    }
}
```

After extensive experimentation, tutorial reading, etc. this question is about WHY the observed behavior exists.

Comment: Are you familiar with type erasure? These generics may not be doing what you think they're doing. Specifically, they're completely removed at runtime within the generic methods: `Integer i = Main.<Integer>getValue(ctx, "STR")` gets compiled down to `Integer i = (Integer) Main.getValue(ctx, "STR")`. Within the generic method, the `T cast = (T) obj` is completely erased, to just `Object cast = obj`. Does that then explain the rest of what you're seeing? (And if you're wondering "well then what's the point, how is that even type-safe?" — note that the compiler warned you about that `(T)` cast.)

Comment: For a bit more detail, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html

Comment: (And for example, if you had done `Foo foo = Main.<Foo>getValue(ctx, "BOOL")`, you would find that you get a ClassCastException at that line. This can cause issues with container classes: if you did `fooList.add(Main.<Foo>getValue(ctx, "BOOL"))`, that would work fine, because the `add` method is _also_ erased. You wouldn't get the exception until `Foo foo = fooList.get(0)`, at which point it may be very difficult to see how that Boolean got into fooList. This is why ignoring that unchecked cast (`(T) obj`) is quite dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: How does your code demonstrate "inference overrides explicit fully qualified typing"? Where does type inference occur in your code? You provided all the type parameters explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *thoroughly* misunderstand how any of this works. Specifically, this:

```
T cast = (T) obj;
System.out.println("Cast to " + cast.getClass().getName());
```

is utter nonsense and betrays that misunderstanding.

A few basic facts:

1. Generics are **entirely** a figment of the compiler's imagination. Most generics disappears *completely* during compilation ('erasure') and whatever is left, **is a comment** as far as the JVM is concerned. The JVM literally does not know what they are.
2. Those warnings you get when you wrote this code shouldn't have been ignored; you did ignore them.
3. You do not understand casts. At all. Nevermind generics.

### Casts

Stop using this word. It's confusing. You're excused; *lots* of tutorials mess this up.

There is only one thing you should term 'a cast'. Which is the language construct `(SomeType) someExpr;`, as in, that literal AST node. It's at the same level as calling the `.lang` in `java.lang.String` a 'select operation on an identifier' - it's fine parlance when debating the 'parse' phase of the compiler and should never be used outside of it.

That's because that one syntactic construct is used for three **completely unrelated things**.

As unrelated as + and + are:

```
String a = "hi"; String b = "hello";
int c = 5; int d = 10;
String z = a + b;
int y = c + d;
```

Note how `a + b` and `c + d` use identical parse basics but mean **completely, utterly, totally unrelated things**. Same goes for casts:

- If the type in the parenthesis is a primitive, **the cast is a primitive conversion operation**. This injects bytecode that takes one kind of primitive (say, a `double`) and converts it to a different kind (say, an `int`). These casts are optional if the conversion is 'widening', and are required otherwise. **This is the only use of cast that converts anything**. At the compilation level, the expression `(int) foo` is of type 'int', and at the runtime level, it introduces a conversion.
- If the type in the parentheses is a non-primitive actual type, **the cast is a type check. *It does not convert anything!*** - at the runtime level, the operation either does nothing (if the thing you are casting is already what you are casting it to), or throws a ClassCastException (if the thing you are casting isn't what you are casting it to). At the compile level, the expression `(String) x` is of type `String` even if x isn't. That's safe: After all, at the runtime level, either `x` already was so that is safe, or we never get there because the code aborts on the spot and goes looking for the nearest catch block if `x` is not. Let's see it in action:

```
Integer i = 5;
String z = (String) i;
```

You, evidently, believe that this means `z` is now the string `"5"`. Not so - that is conversion and that is not happening here. The above would throw a ClassCastException.

- If the type in the parens is generics, **nothing at all happens at runtime** because generics do not exist at runtime. The cast does **literally nothing**, other than tell the compiler to adjust its belief about what type a thing is, **with no guarantee whatsoever that it is true**. Trivial example:

```
<T> void foo() {
  T test = (T) "Hello";
  System.out.println("We aren't even using T!");
}

this.<Integer>foo();
```

would run with zero errors. Even though you'd think: Wait, but, this is casting the string 'Hello' to an Integer which it clearly is not. Because it's not doing anything at runtime at all.

### Casts do not convert. Variables aren't the thing they are pointing at

You seem to believe that this:

```
// For this example, note that:
// class Number extends Object
// class Integer extends Number

Integer i = 5;
System.out.println(i.getClass()); // Integer
Number n = (Number) i;
System.out.println(n.getClass()); // Number
```

**But that is wrong**.

In java, all non-primitive variables are **pointers** (because 'we' dislike that word, we call em 'references', but, potayto potahto). n is a pointer that can point at anything, as long as that thing is either an instance of `Number` or any subtype of `Number`. The above code is fine, because `i` is an instance of `Integer`, which is a subtype of Number. The `.` operation 'dereferences', i.e. follows the pointer, and asks **the object at the other end of that arrow** a question ('what is your class'), it **does not** ask the variable itself that. What is the type of the thing the `n` variable is pointing at? Why, it's the exact same object `i` is pointing at. And it's **an Integer**. In fact, `x.getClass()` **cannot possibly** return `java.lang.Number`, because Number is abstract, and therefore no instance of Number itself can ever be; only instances of non-abstract subtypes of it.

### In summary

- Casting to `(T)` does literal stone cold nothing. Go run `javap` - note how no new bytecode emerges in any way.
- Casting does not convert anything, unless the type in the parens is a primitive. generics can't be primitive, so a cast to a generic thing **cannot convert anything**.
- Type safety is **entirely** guaranteed by the compiler for generics. In contrast to not-generics, where the runtime also guarantees it, and will throw exceptions and errors if you try to mess with it. When the compiler cannot actually guarantee this, then, well, the runtime sure isn't going to do it, so your code becomes meaningless as far as type operations go. The compiler **will always throw a warning in your face** when this happens. You should head those warnings and stop doing it. You always get that warning when casting to generics because **that is simply not a thing you can do**.
- Generics serve to link things at compile time and *that is all they do*. If I want to state: "This method takes 2 arguments and returns something; each time it is called, the caller can pick what type it wants, is simply want to convey that all 3 types are the same: The caller gets to pick a type, but just the one type".

Comment: This is all great info, but a bit harshly written imo. It comes off as chiding OP; but these are all very common beginner mistakes to make (as you even reference a couple times), so I don't see anything in OP's mistake to suggest negligence that I'd rebuke them for. They just failed to grok a concept that a lot of new Java programmers fail to grok. It can be hard for us more experienced people to remember just how confusing this used to be! Take this as you will, of course — and again, the substance of this answer is fantastic.

Comment: Some parts of this answer are somewhat exaggerated. In many cases, generics do leave various traces in compiled code that have consequences at runtime; see e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/280189/40627. And even the OP's examples include some cases of this, e.g. where the compiler has inserted a cast to `Integer` at the boundary of a generic method.

Comment: @ruakh The JVM does not know what they are. You mischaracterise what I wrote in order to engage in some pedantry perhaps? I reread that part, and it's accurate. Your comment less so. As you say, __the compiler__ has inserted that cast. The runtime has no idea what generics are. It knows what those silently injected type assertions do though.

Comment: It's a slight exaggeration to say the JVM doesn't know about them at _all_. They're available via the reflection API, which is of course served by the JVM. That said, it knows very little about them: basically just that they're declared.

Comment: As I said, they are like comments. The JVM does not know what they are. Sure, with reflection, a very small amount of them can be asked about. We're getting thoroughly lost in the pedantry here: The key point is that generics that end up in class files __cannot__ affect what the JVM itself does in any way.

Comment: Sincere thanks for the in-depth answser, @rzwitserloot. I *did* thoroughly misunderstand how this worked, and your explanation of Java's approach to casting/not-casting was very useful.

Side note - there are a couple of places where statements about my "evident beliefs" just weren't accurate. No big deal. In case it helps, I've found that reducing the frequency with which I use the word "you" in troubleshooting conversations has reduced the number of conversations I have which involve hurt feelings.

Comment: @ckamaze I was trying to walk the fine line between being crystal clear that certain beliefs must be adjusted (i.e. the question as asked can only be properly answered by delving a little deeper and undoing some misconceptions first), and being overtly aggressive and, rereading it, I didn't do a very good job. However, I'm not sure how a few choice edits can significantly change its nature, and a complete rewrite seems inappropriate too. All due apologies for those places where the answer presumes a bit too much about your understanding; hopefully that will suffice :)

Comment: No worries, @rzwitserloot. Again, I very much appreciate your expertise.